# Trotz aller technologische[r/n] Fortschritte

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case

Die im Titel zitierte Phrase ist eine gängige Einleitung eines Satzes. 
Welche Variante ist korrekt, und gibt es eine klare grammatikalische Begründung dafür?

- trotz aller technologische**n** Fortschritte
- trotz aller technologische**r** Fortschritte

Die erste Variante geht mir viel flüssiger über die Lippen, und hat auf google deutlich mehr Treffer (als exakte Phrase) als die zweite; aber ich hätte gerne eine überzeugende Erklärung.

Eine dritte Variante mit Dativ ist möglich; diese würde ich aber in einem formalen Kontext erst recht vermeiden:

- trotz allen technologischen Fortschritten

Comment: Ersetze _aller_ doch einfach mal durch _der_ oder _den_ (je nachdem ob du Genitiv oder Dativ bevorzugst).

Comment: Ich möchte darauf hinweisen, dass die Beantwortung der Frage nicht per se mit _trotz_ zu tun hat. Den Eindruck könnte man nämlich gewinnen, wenn man die höchstbewertete Antwort liest.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Zumindest für den Dativ muss man sich die gesamte Konstruktion anschauen (also mit welchem Fall *trotz* steht). Bei der Frage nach technologischere oder technologischen kommt es allerdings tatsächlich rein auf die Flexierung von all + technologisch an.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Der Duden hat einen Abschnitt zur Grammatik](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/trotz) der Präposition `trotz`:

> **Präposition mit Genitiv**:
>   - trotz des Regens
>   - trotz vieler Ermahnungen
>
> **Besonders süddeutsch, schweizerisch und österreichisch auch mit Dativ**:
>   - trotz dem Regen
>   - trotz vielen Ermahnungen
>
> **Allgemein häufiger mit Dativ**,
>   wenn **Artikel oder Pronomen fehlen**, und i**mmer, wenn der Genitiv im
>   Plural nicht erkennbar ist oder wenn ein Genitivattribut zwischen
>   »trotz« und das davon abhängende Substantiv tritt**:
>   Ebenso in:
>   - trotz
>   heftigem Regen
>   -  trotz nassem Asphalt
>   -  trotz Beweisen
>   *[...]*
>
> Ein **stark gebeugtes Substantiv** im Singular
>   ohne Artikel und Attribut bleibt oft ungebeugt:
>   - trotz Regen [und Kälte]
>   - trotz Umbau

Aus meiner Sicht ergeben sich hierbei zwei Interpretationsweisen:

### 1. `all` ist hier als [Pronomen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/all) verwendet

Der Duden klassifiziert `all` als Pronomen. Demnach muss im Hochdeutschen die Konstruktion mit Genitiv stehen.

Tatsächlich findet sich *trotz aller Bemühungen* auch als Beispiel im Duden.

Gen. Pl. von Fortschritt ist *[der Fortschritte [m]](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Fortschritt)*, `technologisch` als Adjektiv muss also auch in den Genitiv Plural flektiert werden. Der Genitiv Plural Maskulin von `technologisch` ist [der technologischer](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:technologisch) (Starke Deklination).

**Anmerkung:** Wie **[@idmean](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/41802/29833)** in seiner Antwort bemerkte, ist die starke Flektieren nach Formen von `all` veraltet. Modern ist demnach **trotz aller technologischen Fortschritte richtig**.

Veraltet (aber immer noch gültig) ist: **trotz aller technologischer Fortschritte**

### 2. `all` ist hier als Zahlwort verwendet

Dies würde es rechtfertigen, den Dativ zu verwenden: Es steht ein Genitivattribut zwischen trotz und dem davon abhängenden Substantiv.

Prinzipiell würde es dann heißen **"trotz allen technologischen Fortschritten".**

---

### Fazit

Da der Duden aber die Kombination "trotz aller" explizit als Beispiel anführt, würde ich **den Genitiv als Regelfall** verwenden und den Dativ in allen Fällen weglassen. `aller technologischen` ist moderner als `aller technologischer`, und es ist (noch) Geschmacksache welche Form man verwendet.

Answer (score 7):

> Nach all- stehen in der Regel die schwachen Endungen. Die starken Endungen gelten als veraltet.
>    [Link](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Deklinationstyp/Schwach.html)

"Trotz aller technologischen Fortschritte" ist [schwach flektiert](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:technologisch), geht uns deshalb wohl flüssiger über die Lippen.

Es ist beides gleich richtig und es empfiehlt sich normalerweise das zu nehmen, was dir am natürlichsten vorkommt. Besonders, wenn veraltete Formen verwendet werden, wirkt das ansonsten schnell sehr künstlich.